# grails heroku plugin - unable to resolve class grails.plugin.cloudsupport.AbstractCloudTagLib

Tags: grails, heroku

When I run the

```
git push heroku master
```

command, I get the following error (below).   Per one this [thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?120870-Cloud-Foundry-Plug-in), I uninstalled the heroku plugin, installed the cloud-support plugin, and re-installed the heroku plugin.  That didn't change the error.   I entered a JIRA on this at the plugin, but am posting here so that there is an easy reference to whatever solution the grails folks are able to provide or in case dialogue on the problem/solution is required.

Thanks

Error is:

[mkdir] Created dir: /app/.grails/1.3.7/projects/build_36v61myh1movb/plugins/tomcat-1.3.7
   [unzip] Expanding: /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/cache/org.grails.plugins/tomcat/zips/tomcat-1.3.7.zip into

/app/.grails/1.3.7/projects/build_36v61myh1movb/plugins/tomcat-1.3.7
       Installed plugin tomcat-1.3.7 to location /app/.grails/1.3.7/projects/build_36v61myh1movb/plugins/tomcat-

1.3.7. ...
       Executing tomcat-1.3.7 plugin post-install script ...
       Plugin tomcat-1.3.7 installed
       Plugin provides the following new scripts:
       ------------------------------------------
       grails tomcat
           [mkdir] Created dir: /app/.grails/1.3.7/projects/build_36v61myh1movb/plugin-classes
         [groovyc] Compiling 106 source files to /app/.grails/1.3.7/projects/build_36v61myh1movb/plugin-classes
         [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
         [groovyc] /app/.grails/1.3.7/projects/build_36v61myh1movb/plugins/heroku-1.0/grails-

**app/taglib/grails/plugin/heroku/HerokuTagLib.groovy: 17: unable to resolve class grails.plugin.cloudsupport.AbstractCloudTagLib**
         [groovyc]  @ line 17, column 1.
         [groovyc]    import grails.plugin.cloudsupport.AbstractCloudTagLib
         [groovyc]    ^
         [groovyc]
         [groovyc] /app/.grails/1.3.7/projects/build_36v61myh1movb/plugins/heroku-1.0/grails-

app/taglib/grails/plugin/heroku/HerokuTagLib.groovy: 22: unable to resolve class grails.plugin.cloudsupport.Abstr
actCloudTagLib
         [groovyc]  @ line 22, column 1.
         [groovyc]    class HerokuTagLib extends AbstractCloudTagLib {
         [groovyc]    ^
         [groovyc]
         [groovyc] /app/.grails/1.3.7/projects/build_36v61myh1movb/plugins/heroku-

1.0/src/groovy/grails/plugin/heroku/HerokuBeanPostprocessor.groovy: 17: unable to resolve class

grails.plugin.cloudsupport.A
bstractCloudBeanPostprocessor
         [groovyc]  @ line 17, column 1.
         [groovyc]    import grails.plugin.cloudsupport.AbstractCloudBeanPostprocessor
         [groovyc]    ^
         [groovyc]
         [groovyc] /app/.grails/1.3.7/projects/build_36v61myh1movb/plugins/heroku-

1.0/src/groovy/grails/plugin/heroku/HerokuBeanPostprocessor.groovy: 27: unable to resolve class

grails.plugin.cloudsupport.A
bstractCloudBeanPostprocessor
         [groovyc]  @ line 27, column 1.
         [groovyc]    class HerokuBeanPostprocessor extends AbstractCloudBeanPostprocessor {
         [groovyc]    ^
         [groovyc]
         [groovyc] /app/.grails/1.3.7/projects/build_36v61myh1movb/plugins/heroku-

1.0/src/groovy/grails/plugin/heroku/HerokuMongoBeanConfigurer.groovy: 17: unable to resolve class

grails.plugin.cloudsupport
.AbstractMongoBeanConfigurer
         [groovyc]  @ line 17, column 1.
         [groovyc]    import grails.plugin.cloudsupport.AbstractMongoBeanConfigurer
         [groovyc]    ^
         [groovyc]
         [groovyc] /app/.grails/1.3.7/projects/build_36v61myh1movb/plugins/heroku-

1.0/src/groovy/grails/plugin/heroku/HerokuMongoBeanConfigurer.groovy: 24: unable to resolve class

grails.plugin.cloudsupport
.AbstractMongoBeanConfigurer
         [groovyc]  @ line 24, column 1.
         [groovyc]    class HerokuMongoBeanConfigurer extends AbstractMongoBeanConfigurer {
         [groovyc]    ^
         [groovyc]
         [groovyc] 6 errors
       Error executing script Compile: : Compilation Failed
       : Compilation Failed
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:391)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
       Caused by: : Compilation Failed
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.compile(Groovyc.java:920)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.execute(Groovyc.java:607)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at Compile$_run_closure4_closure10.doCall(Compile:117)
        at Compile$_run_closure4_closure10.doCall(Compile)
        at Compile$_run_closure10.doCall(Compile:280)
        at Compile$_run_closure10.call(Compile)
        at Compile$_run_closure4.doCall(Compile:104)
        at Compile$_run_closure3.doCall(Compile:69)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
        ... 10 more
       Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
       /app/.grails/1.3.7/projects/build_36v61myh1movb/plugins/heroku-1.0/grails-

app/taglib/grails/plugin/heroku/HerokuTagLib.groovy: 17: unable to resolve class

grails.plugin.cloudsupport.AbstractCloudTagLib

---

---

Problems before this, note git push gives me no opportunity to respond to the [y,n] prompts:

```
   Plugin mail-1.0 installed
   Resolving plugin JAR dependencies ...
   Executing spring-security-ui-0.1.2 plugin post-install script ...
   Plugin spring-security-ui-0.1.2 installed
   Plugin provides the following new scripts:
   ------------------------------------------
   grails s2ui-override
   You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [mail-1.0]. Do you want to upgrade this version? [y,n]
   Invalid option 'null' - must be one of: [y,n]

   You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [mail-1.0]. Do you want to upgrade this version? [y,n]
   Invalid option 'null' - must be one of: [y,n]

   You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [mail-1.0]. Do you want to upgrade this version? [y,n]
   Invalid option 'null' - must be one of: [y,n]

   No valid response entered - giving up asking.
   Plugin mail-1.0-SNAPSHOT install aborted ...
   You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [spring-security-core-1.2.7.1]. Do you want to upgrade this version? [y,n]
   Invalid option 'null' - must be one of: [y,n]

   You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [spring-security-core-1.2.7.1]. Do you want to upgrade this version? [y,n]
   Invalid option 'null' - must be one of: [y,n]

   You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [spring-security-core-1.2.7.1]. Do you want to upgrade this version? [y,n]
   Invalid option 'null' - must be one of: [y,n]

   No valid response entered - giving up asking.
   Plugin spring-security-core-1.2.1 install aborted ...
   You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [jquery-1.7.1]. Do you want to upgrade this version? [y,n]
   Invalid option 'null' - must be one of: [y,n]

   You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [jquery-1.7.1]. Do you want to upgrade this version? [y,n]
   Invalid option 'null' - must be one of: [y,n]

   You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [jquery-1.7.1]. Do you want to upgrade this version? [y,n]
   Invalid option 'null' - must be one of: [y,n]

   No valid response entered - giving up asking.
   Plugin jquery-1.6.1.1 install aborted ...
       [mkdir] Created dir: /app/.grails/1.3.7/projects/build_28p9jo3vo48wb/plugin-classes
     [groovyc] Compiling 106 source files to /app/.grails/1.3.7/projects/build_28p9jo3vo48wb/plugin-classes
     [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
     [groovyc] /app/.grails/1.3.7/projects/build_28p9jo3vo48wb/plugins/heroku-1.0/grails-app/taglib/grails/plugin/heroku/HerokuTagLib.groovy: 17: unable to resolve class grails.plugin.cloudsupport.Abstr
```

actCloudTagLib
         [groovyc]  @ line 17, column 1.
         [groovyc]    import grails.plugin.cloudsupport.AbstractCloudTagLib
         [groovyc]    ^
         [groovyc]

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem with grails 1.3.7.

As suggested by Burt, adding the following to your BuildConfig.groovy will resolve the problem:

```
compile ':cloud-support:1.0.8'
```

I've followed the Basic Tutorial of Burt's [here](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-heroku/docs/manual/guide/3%20Tutorials.html#3.1%20Basic%20Tutorial), after the above was added, my web-app compiled and deployed to Heroku successfully.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  Problem is from spring-security-ui plugin; heroku plugin cannot work with it.  Burt said he would be fixing it this week.  Do you by chance have either spring-security-ui or spring-security-core plugins installed?  If so, are you able to make it work?

Comment: Nope, just vanilla grails app with the heroku plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the cloud-support plugin is the fix. Try running `grails clean` and `grails compile` to get it to resolve the dependencies.

Comment: I've tried every combination of cleaning, rebuilding, installing the cloud-support plugin either before or after the heroku plugin, and I get the same error.  Can you double check this on your system (Grails 1.3.7)?  Also, what is the name of this jar file that contains these class files?

Comment: Also note, I get some errors before this that it seems to run past and I don't get a chance to respond to.  I'll include that error output above in the problem statement.   Thanks.

Comment: I can see the AbstractCloudTagLib.groovy, AbstractCloudBeanPostprocessor.groovy, and AbstractCloudBeanPostprocessor.groovy files in my system under C:/Users/Ray/.grails/1.3.7/projects/Momentum/plugins/cloud-support-1.0.8/src/groovy/grails/plugin/cloussupport.

Comment: I'm looking through the push output to see if there is a place I can copy these 3 files to satisfy the compiler but it's not obvious as grails appears to be re-installed as the plugins are. Is there a place I can copy these 3 files and satisfy the compiler?  And/or is it possible to include them in the heroku plugin?

Comment: No, those are the wrong approaches. The transitive dependency is failing in 1.3.x but that's fixable by installing the cloud-support plugin. This will work in 2.0 - the transitive install works fine. You can also try adding the plugins as dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy in the plugins section, e.g. `build ":heroku:1.0"` and `build ":cloud-support:1.0.8"`. But I'm guessing that the mess of error messages that you're seeing about upgrading plugins is the real culprit.

Comment: You should try an app that doesn't have spring-security-ui. It looks like that's causing the dependency problems. I'm working on a new version that should be out this week that will work in 2.0 and work better in 1.3.x.

Comment: I tried adding build ":heroku:1.0" and build ":cloud-support:1.0.8" in the plugins section but still same error.  Will pull out spring-security-ui tomorrow and see what happens.  Are you saying I should upgrade to 2.0 at this point or is that only something you'll know this week?

Comment: Heroku works fine with 2.0, but spring-security-ui doesn't, so to test you'll need to uninstall spring-security-ui. Once the update is out it should all work.

Comment: Do you think the update will work with 1.3.7 & Spring-Security-UI?

Comment: :-)  I guess the conversion from 1.3.7 to 2.0 shouldn't be too big of a deal .. has that been what you guys found (I've got about 12 domain classes, been developing the app for 3 months)?

Comment: Burt - is there a way using this plugin for a project associate who is just updating css/images (i.e. look & feel stuff) that doesn't require a source code changes, to deploy?  I don't know how Grails works in general here, allowing graphics folks to deploy updates to sites (that don't involve code changes).

Comment: Sort of. Once you have created and deployed the application, updates are simple - just commit the changes to Git and push again. But a static file change will restart the application just like a code change. I don't think there's a way around that, but you could ask on the Heroku forums.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I meant, avoiding a restart for static file changes.  Seems like it should be possible, but don't understand enough about things actually run on server in (?) WAR file structure.

Comment: Burt - do you have any update on the Heroku plugin with Spring-security-ui for Grails 2.0? (I'm migrating to 2.0)

Comment: I forgot I relied as heavily as I did on the Spring-security-ui, e.g. also for registration.

Comment: Burt - do you expect that the updated Spring-security-ui will work with the Heroku plugin?  Anything special that needs to be done?

Comment: As far as I know, as long as all the dependencies are ok, it should work.